# ошибка при роботе с SQLITE

Tags: python

```
import sqlite3 as sql

conn = sql.connect('itproger.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXSITS users (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    password varchar() 
) ''')
conn.commit()

user_name = input('Write your name:')
user_pass = input('Write your password:')

cur.execute('INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES ("%s", "%s")'%(user_name, user_pass))
conn.commit()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Ошибка:   File "D:\PROJECT\main.py", line 6, in 
cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXSITS users (
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "EXSITS": syntax error
Запускаю все через тереминал в Visual Studio Code, единствиное решение к которому я пришёл это снисти виндов под 0 и роботать на чистой системе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибки в коде sql запроса.

Вот так в 6 строке должно быть, что касается ошибок, то типичные

`EXSITS > EXISTS`
и
`password varchar() > password varchar`

```
cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    password varchar 
) ''')
```